# Difficulty proving that multiplication of left cosets is well-defined.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I am trying to prove that given two cosets $x + W, y + W \in G/W$, the product of these two cosets is $xy + W \in G/W$ is well-defined. In other words, if $x + W = x' + W$ and $y + W = y' + W$, that means that $(x + W)(y + W) = (x' + W)(y' + W)$.

$G = \mathbb{F}[x]$ and $W = \{h(x)f(x) \,\, | \,\, f(x) \in G\}$, with $h(x)$ being fixed.

I started out by observing that $x' = x + w$ and $y' = y + w'$, with $w, w' \in W$. My intuition was to somehow expand $(x + w)(y + w')$ and then use the two observations to simplify that to $(x' + w)(y' + w)$. However, I wasn't able to accomplish that and am quite lost as to the general direction in which my proof should follow.

Comment: You tag this as group theory, yet you have both multiplication and addition in your calculations. Could you be more specific about what kind of objects $G$ and $W$ are?

Comment: @Arthur $G$ is a group of polynomials and $W$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: Because it looks to me like you have $G$ a _ring_ of polynomials and $W$ is a subgroup of the additive group of $G$.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, you are correct. I updated my question.

Comment: I cannot wrap my head around $G$ not being a group.

Comment: @Randall I was simply provided that $G = \mathbb{F}[x]$. It did not state whether G was a group or a ring.

Comment: @Randall $G = \mathbb{F}[x]$ and $W = \{h(x)f(x) \,\, | \,\, f(x) \in G\}$, with $h(x)$ being fixed.

Comment: @Arthur $G = \mathbb{F}[x]$ and $W = \{h(x)f(x) \,\, | \,\, f(x) \in G\}$, with $h(x)$ being fixed.

Comment: The group operation is addition. You will need to use that $h(x)f(x)+h(x)g(x)=h(x)(f(x)+g(x))$.

Comment: Although $G$ is an additive group, you are looking at the **ring** structure, as you are using both addition and mu,tipkication. So this needs to be tagged properly.

Comment: $$\begin{align}
xy-x'y' & = (xy-x'y) + (x'y-x'y') \\ {} \\
& = (x-x')y + x'(y-y')
\end{align}$$
Since $x,x'$ are both in the same coset, $x-x'\in W.$ Similarly $y-y'\in W.$ (Maybe I'll say more about this later.) $\qquad$

Comment: If $W$ consists of all multiples of some fixed $h\in G$, then $W$ isn't just an additive subgroup, $W$ is an ideal. These things matter. They should've been included from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different notation may be useful, using functions. You want to prove that if
$p(x) + W = p'(x) + W$ and $q(x)+ W = q'(x) + W$, then $p(x)q(x) + W = p'(x)q'(x) + W$.

You know that $p(x) = p'(x) + h(x)f(x)$ and $q(x) = q'(x) + h(x)g(x)$, which is exactly what you wrote, just writing explicitly your $w$ and $w'$. If you now multiply and factor out $h(x)$, you should be able to finish your proof.

Comment: You are done. You have written $p(x)q(x)$ as the sum of $p'(x)q'(x)$ and an element in $W$, since $W$ is defined as the multiples of $h(x)$. So you have proved that $p(x)q(x)$ belongs to $p'(x)q'(x) + W$, and so $p(x)q(x) + W = p'(x)q'(x) + W$. Right?

Comment: @Fernando Torres Why did you delete your comment? It was perfectly fine.